# printf выводит кракозябры

Tags: c, printf

В соседней функции выводит нечто:

```
HPDF_Page_TextOut (page, 10, height - 40, datetime);

// Вывод

H옾 @
```

Вот код функции, которая генерирует дату/время:

```
int datetime(void)
{

   setlocale(LC_ALL, ".UTF-8");

   time_t t;
   time(&t);
   printf("%s\n", ctime(&t));

   return 0;
    
}
```

Если закавычить `setlocale(LC_ALL, ".UTF-8");`, то выводит:

```
H예|$袻H|$蘻HǨ
```

:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В коде `HPDF_Page_TextOut (page, 10, height - 40, datetime)` функция `datetime` не вызывается. Указатель на функцию передаётся в качестве строки для печати. Вы печатаете код функции до первого нуля в нём. Когда вы "кавычите" строку, вы меняете код и меняете то что попадает в PDF.

Вызов `datetime()` ситуацию не исправит. Функция должна возвращать строку, а она возвращает целое число ноль.

Исправить можно так:

```
const char *datetime(void)
{
   time_t t;
   time(&t);
   char *s = ctime(&t);
   s[strlen(s) - 1] = '\0';  /* remove trailing '\n' */
   return s;
}

...

    HPDF_Page_TextOut(page, 10, height - 40, datetime())
```

Comment: а как же быть? Мне нужно в подзаголовке выводить текущую дату, а как реализовать, теперь совсем не ясно. Это можно как-то в моём случае решить?

Comment: спасибо огромное! Скажите, а почему выводится квадратик в конце? :)

`Fri Mar 22 14:28:50 2024 ` (тут не отображается).

Comment: Это перевод строки. В последней версии кода я его стёр.